# Help with Test Class on Batch Apex

Tags: apex

All, need help with test class on Batch apex. Below is batch apex code which make 2 callouts (for Token and actual data) however i`m not able to get test coverege on this class. All I have is 7% coverage. Can someone please help?

```
    global class CalloutsAccounts implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts{


   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String query =  'SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query); 
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){
        HttpRequest obj = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        String reqBody = '{ "user": "Username", "passwd": "user_password" }';
        obj.setMethod('POST');
        obj.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        obj.setEndPoint('https://test.samplepoint.com/api/UserSrvs.svc/Login');
        obj.setBody(reqBody);
        obj.getheader('Auth-Token');
        res = http.send(obj);

                authtoken objAuthenticationInfo = (authtoken)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(), authtoken.class);
String token = res.getHeader('Auth-Token');


        Http h1 = new Http();
        HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
        String reqBody2 = ' {"Accountype" : "workforce"}'; 
        req1.setHeader('Auth-Token', token);
        req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req1.setMethod('POST');
         req1.setBody(reqBody2);

        req1.setEndpoint('https://test.samplepoint.com/api/accservices.svc/accountfeed');
        HttpResponse res1 = h1.send(req1);



                   JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res1.getBody());
                    parser.nextToken();
                     parser.nextValue();

                    String fieldName = parser.getCurrentName();
                    String fieldValue = parser.getText(); 

    accParser deserializeResults3 =  new accParser ();
    deserializeResults3 = (accParser)System.JSON.deserialize(fieldValue, accParser.class);
     List < accParser.cls_account> advisorList = new List< accParser.cls_account>();
    advisorList = deserializeResults3.root.accounts.account;

           Map <Decimal,Id> AdvisorMap = New Map  <Decimal,Id>   ();

        List <Account> advisorAccList = [SELECT Id, Fact_ID__c, RecordTypeID FROM Account WHERE RecordTypeid = '0124100000091Ho'];

        For (Account Acs : advisorAccList) {
            If (Acs.Fact_ID__c != null)
            AdvisorMap.put(Acs.Fact_ID__c, Acs.ID);
                }


             Map <String,Id> HouseholdMap = New Map  <String,Id>   ();

        List <Account> advisorAccList1 = [SELECT Id, SSCN__c, RecordTypeID FROM Account WHERE RecordTypeid = '012410000009Il6'];

        For (Account Acs1 : advisorAccList1) {
            If (Acs1.SSCN__c != null)
            HouseholdMap.put(Acs1.SSCN__c, Acs1.ID);
            system.debug('@@@'+HouseholdMap);
                }



List<Financial_Account__c> lstAccount = new List<Financial_Account__c>();
for(accountParser.cls_account cand : advisorList){
    Financial_Account__c PFA = New Financial_Account__c();
    //PFA.Cirrus_Unique_ID__c =  cand.account_id;

    //Map Advisor Lookup
   PFA.Advisor_ID__c = cand.advisor_id; 
   PFA.Advisor__c = AdvisorMap.get(PFA.Advisor_ID__c );  

    //Map Household Client Lookup
    PFA.Household_ID2__c = cand.household_id;
   if (HouseholdMap.get(PFA.Household_ID2__c) == null) {
       PFA.Client__c = '0013C000003Ywet'; 
} else if (PFA.Household_ID2__c != null) {
         PFA.Client__c = HouseholdMap.get(PFA.Household_ID2__c);  
}




    PFA.Unique_ID__c =  cand.account_id;
    PFA.Financial_Account_Number__c =  cand.accountnum;
    PFA.Account_Type__c =  cand.account;
    PFA.Tax_Status__c=  cand.taxablestatus;
    PFA.Investment_Objective__c =  cand.objective;
    if (cand.inception_date != null) {
    PFA.Account_Opening__c = date.parse(cand.inception);
        }
        if (cand.perf_begin_date != null) {
    PFA.perf_begin_date__c = date.parse(cand.perfdate);
        }
    // if (cand.household_id != null) {
  //  PFA.Household_ID__c = cand.housedate_id;
  //      }
    PFA.Account_Type__c =  cand.account_type;
   // PFA.Client__c =  '0013C000003CRTr'; LOOKUP TO ACCOUNTS
    PFA.compute_flg__c = cand.compute_flg;
    PFA.Account_Description__c = cand.description;
    PFA.fwc_hh_id__c = cand.fwc_hh_id;
        if (cand.termination_date != null) {
    PFA.termination_date__C = date.parse(cand.termination_date);
        }
        if (cand.last_date != null) {
    PFA.last_date__c = date.parse(cand.last_date);
        }
    PFA.Custodian_Id__c = cand.custodian_id;
    PFA.billing_account_num__c = cand.billing_account_num;
    PFA.rebal_method__c = cand.rebal_method;




    lstAccount.add(PFA);
}


Boolean isUpsertfirstTime = true;
try {
    upsert lstAccount Financial_Account_Number__c;
}catch (DMLException e) {
                System.debug('Re-trying');
                if(isUpsertfirstTime){
                        upsert lstAccount Financial_Account_Number__c;
                                isUpsertfirstTime = false;
              }
}


   }       

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
              CalloutsAccounts2 myaccBatch = new CalloutsAccounts2();
      Id batchProcessId = Database.executeBatch(myacctBatch);

   }
}
```

Mock:

```
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
        // and method.
               System.assertEquals('https://test.samplepoint.com/api/UserSrvs.svc/', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('POST', req.getMethod()); 

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.setBody(''{ "user": "Username", "passwd": "user_password" }');
        res.setHeader('Auth-Token', '3+yV8B+7iSTu7Oj4alK4/fJPY1a5VRhAre6jG5vx6kDTXMOENFWJqAIQpuYE8nOdLwDmQBdo=');
 res.setStatusCode(200);         
        return res;
    }
}
```

TEst Class:

```
@isTest
private class CalloutClassTest {
     @isTest static void testCallout() {
        // Set mock callout class 

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
        Test.startTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new CalloutsAccounts(), 100);
        Test.stopTest();

    }
```

Comment: I don't see you inserting an Account record in your test class

Comment: You need to have a test record so that your start method can get it in the Query

Answer (score 3):

Your test class is missing data for it to actually use. In this instance, your batch is using this query:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1
```

Salesforce will be querying for this and think "hey, there's no data to use! There's no point in executing anything because there's nothing to execute over!"

Thus whilst the `start()` method will get covered, the `execute()` and `finish()` methods won't.

> All I have is 7% coverage

This, I suspect is your 7%.

So in your test class you'll want to create something like this above your `testCallout()` method:

```
@testSetup static void test_data() {
    Account acc = new Account(
        Name = 'My Test Account'
    );

    INSERT acc;
}
```

This will insert test data for you to use in your test class and thus give your batch class something to process.

I will say I'm confused as to why you're putting a `LIMIT 1` on your Batch class' query as it kind of defeats the point of even using a Batch class. Just use:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account
```

When you're executing the batch class, you kind of, do this as part of the second parameter:

```
Database.executeBatch(new CalloutsAccounts(), 100);
```

Here you're saying, execute this batch and do them over multiple batches of 100 records. There might be 1 batch of 1 records or 100 batches with 10000 records in the total.

**Edit**
As @AdrianLarson points out also, avoid using hard-coded anything. Instead, you'll want to query for the `DeveloperName`. If you're unsure what that is, you can run a query using workbench or debugging via anonymous apex in the developer console, for example, something like:

```
RecordType rt = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE Id = '0124100000091Ho'];

System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@' + rt.DeveloperName);
```

In your code you should then query for the `RecordType` by using that `DeveloperName`. It's not too dissimillar to the above query:

```
RecordType rt = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName = 'MyRecordType'];
```

Then in your query reference it, such as below:

```
List <Account> advisorAccList1 = [SELECT Id, SSCN__c, RecordTypeID FROM Account WHERE RecordTypeid = rt.Id];
```

You should use DeveloperName because the name is effectively a label that may change and Ids are inconsistent across Sandboxes and Production environments.

Comment: Yeah. Very much missing the point.

Comment: @Dan... Thank you for replying. You are right, only start method is being covered. If I remove 'SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1', query part from start method,  it gives me an error stating no query in start so I added a small statement. Sorry, I`m new to Apex. is there a better way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Also, hard-coded ids are very bad and you should avoid them *at all costs*.

Comment: @TomSimmons Just remove the `LIMIT 1` so your query will be `SELECT Id FROM Account`.

Comment: @TomSimmons It's also worth noting that `Database.getQueryLocator()` returns up to 50 million records whereas typical `SOQL` returns 50k I believe. So unless your database is massive, you've likely nothing to worry about with respect to governor limits.

Comment: Thank you Dan and Adrian, much appreciate your help. As suggested, I tried adding an account to the test method but its now giving me an error "System.NullPointerException: Argument 2 cannot be null". Could you please help?

Comment: @isTest
private class CalloutClassTest {
     @ isTest static void testCallout() {
         
           Account acc = new Account( Name = 'My Test Account' );

      Insert acc;

        CalloutsAccounts CA= new CalloutsAccounts ();

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
        Test.startTest();

        Database.executeBatch(new CalloutsAccounts ());
        Test.stopTest();

    }
}